# The library youtubeExtractor give me an error

Tags: c#, dll, youtube

I'm trying to make an application that download videos from YouTube using the [youtubeExtractor library](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor). The code has no errors, but when I click *download*, it gives me this error:

> YoutubeExtractor.VideoNotAvailableException: Video is removed or has
>   an age restriction.

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using YoutubeExtractor;
using VideoExtractor;

namespace Url_DownLoad
{

    public partial class Url_DownLoad : Form
    {
        
        public Url_DownLoad()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Url_DownLoad_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            //WebClient client = new WebClient();
            //client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
            //client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
        }
        private void Btn_Scarica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Download();
        }
    void Download()
        {
            IEnumerable <VideoInfo> videos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(Txt_Url.Text);
            VideoInfo vi = videos.First(info => info.VideoType == VideoType.Mp4 && info.Resolution == Convert.ToInt32(360));
            if (vi.RequiresDecryption)
            {
                DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(vi);
            }
            var videodownload = new VideoDownloader(vi, @"C: \Users\Nicola\Desktop\" + vi.Title + vi.VideoExtension);
            videodownload.DownloadFinished += Videodownload_DownloadFinished;
            
            videodownload.Execute();
        }
        void Videodownload_DownloadFinished(object s,EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DownLoad Terminato");
        }
        //void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        //{
        //    progressBar1.Maximum = (int) e.TotalBytesToReceive / 100;
        //    progressBar1.Value = (int) e.BytesReceived / 100;
        //}

     }
}
```

Comment: apparently the video does no longer exist or has an age restriction

Comment: the video exists ... I also enter in YouTube with my credential (login)
all video link in YouTube  give me the same error

Comment: Does it have an age restriction?

Comment: no restrictions .. is small video clip about 2 minutes .. Golden retriver dog. In any case any video i try to download i receive the same error ….. here is a link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cgn0QuThN3o

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a bug in the library as stated in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor/issues/374).

Comment: this library is made available by Visual Studio 2017 ... a feedback would probably be a good thing

Comment: You can add a comment to the issue I linked, that you experience the same problem.